# Sending a shell command in java program

Tags: java, shell

I'm trying to execute the following shell command in a java program:

```
 curl -k -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"COMMAND":"DISCSTATUS","USER":"PMDC"}' 
 https://167.254.226.215/DcnWebSvr/DcnSvrCmd
```

It returns the string

```
 {"Result":"SUCCESS"}
```

From the terminal, this command works fine. But when I try to do it from a java program, I don't get the same result.

Here's my code:

```
 StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("curl","-k", "-X", "POST","- H","\"Content-Type:application/json\"",
                                                "-d","'{\"COMMAND\":\"DISCSTATUS\",\"USER\":\"PMDC\"}'", 
                                                "https://167.254.226.215/DcnWebSvr/DcnSvrCmd");
    builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
    try {

        Process process = builder.start();
        InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            output.append(line + "\n");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return output.toString();
```

However, it doesn't output the correct string. Instead, it seems like it's recognizing the command as some kind of transfer, as this is the output I'm getting:

```
   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100    40    0     0  100    40      0    164 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   165
```

Is it just some syntax error that I keep overlooking? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `curl --silent` to suppress the progress information.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my issue. The problem was that I was using single quotes where I didn't need them in the ProcessBuilder. Same as here:

[Execute curl from java with processbuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442344/execute-curl-from-java-with-processbuilder)

Answer (score -1):

It is due to a misunderstanding of how your command interpreter (a shell, for instance) treats the command line versus how it is launched in a process.

A `ProcessBuilder` expects raw arguments.

Just from the shell, consider this:

```
# Both commands will be the same
ls
"ls"
```

Yes, that is the same thing. The quotes are in fact interpreted by THE SHELL. But the real process behind the scenes will only ever see what the shell has processed beforehand -- in this case, a simple `ls`.

Try it in your shell; you'll see that all of these have the same result:

```
'l's
'ls'
'l'"s"
'l''s'
```

Try and see what it means for your arguments to `ProcessBuilder`... What I said is not only relevant for the command but for *all* arguments...

Comment: Downvoter please explain. This is EXACTLY the problem encountered here.